# Bootstrap CSS scrollspy, everything diaspears when scrolling

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I have a strange problem with Bootstrap Css scrollspy.

On my page neu.ferienhaus-lieby.at. When you click on "Zimmer" and you try to scroll, the whole content disappear. When i use the "data-spy" tag on the body. It seems to work. But only the last element is marked as active.

This is my index.html

http://pastebin.com/GtKRTXyG

Thank you